# What can be the possible reason that different tab in same browser (Chrome) is giving different result for "for-in" loop over an array?

Tags: javascript

Here is the JavaScript code snippet executed in same Browser console but within different tab having different web project opened.

```js
var myArray = [0];
for (var val in myArray) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

Result in First Tab: 0
Result in Second Tab: 0,remove.

What can be the possible reason?

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example of something that runs this code and presents with the described problem?

Comment: Where does the `remove` even come from? You are not logging it in the current code, so it might not be related to your code at all. Maybe a plugin or extension? Anyway, can't duplicate.

Comment: Has something possibly [altered the `Array` prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agenY.png) in the second tab?  Perhaps to add `remove` functionality to it?  The output you're seeing is one reason why it's sometimes a bad idea to do so.

Comment: There are two possibilities.  a. some code that you're not showing us is adding 'remove' to your array.  b.  some other code is writing 'remove' to the console.  You could rule out b by adding a marker to your output so you know which you have generated ...log("Value is:"+val) would do it

Comment: @somethinghere - following the comment, I figured out that , there was a Array.prototype extension method in another tab. so I had two choices remove the extension method Or use "for" loop instead of "for-in" over array. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any possibility it can work differently. You can try

```
var myArray=[0];
for(var val in myArray){
 console.log(val);
 debugger;
};
```

And see what are the values of the variable. There is a rare chance one of them is immutable.

Comment: That seems like a comment, not an answer. If you can't comment yet, you will have to earn some reputation first.